# Solution verification: $m(A)>1$ implies $\exists x,y\in A$ s.t. $x-y\in\mathbb{N}.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ with $m(A)>1$. Prove that there exists $x,y\in A$ such that $x-y$ is a positive integer. ($m$ is the Lebesgue measure.)

I think I have an interesting idea to solve this which I present below and would like to confirm if it is correct.

Fix $y\in A$. Then we need to show that there is a positive integer $n$ such that $x=y+n\in A$. i.e. $y\in A-n$. In words, my idea is to instead prove that there is a translate of $A$ that also contains $y$.

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi_{A-n}(y)dy=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{\mathbb{R}} \chi_{A-n}(y)dy= \sum_{n=1}^\infty m(A-n)>\sum_{n=1}^\infty1=\infty$$

This implies that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\chi_{A-n}(y)>0$ which implies that that there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $y\in A-n$. Then $y=x-n$, for some $x\in A$ and thus $x-y=n$, as required.

Question: Is this correct? If not, can it be fixed so that my idea can still be applied?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Isn't it true that $A \in \Bbb R \Longrightarrow m(A) = 0$?  Perhaps you mean $A \subset \Bbb R$ instead!

Comment: Corrected, thanks.

Comment: Your proof is fine. Quite neat, in fact.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Great, thanks!

Comment: The only part I think would need justification is the change of the sum and integral, since the sum is infinite.

Comment: @StevenCreech In my head I justified it by MCT. MCT works for extended real valued functions, I believe.

Comment: @omololo After looking at it some more, I am a bit unsure, let us say that $A=(0,1/2)$, then I think your "proof" would still work in the same way except you would end up with a sum of $1/2$ instead of $1$, but it would still go to infinity, so I think something strange is going on as you say that you are fixing some $y$, but then when you integrate the $y$ is no longer fixed (or perhaps I am mistaken).

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Say $A\subset [-d, d]$, place $(n+1)$ translates by $0$, $1$, $\ldots$, $n$ into a segment $[-d, d+n]$. For some $n$ large enough, we will have
$$(n+1) \mu(A) > \mu([-d, d+n])$$
so two of the translates will intersect.